# GIT: Detached Head -> make current head

Tags: git, github, reset, head

I committed by mistake a big docker image tar file and then pushed it.
When I noticed the push was taking too long I aborted it.
Then, I removed the tar and did a new commit (instead of amending the previous).

I decided to go back, doing a `git reset -soft`, remove the file on the commit it was added, and amending that commit.
(I think I checked out a commit sometime in this timeline)
Then I push with `---force-with-lease`

but now I get this with git status:

```
HEAD detached from adc7f05
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

(the unstaged changes is only a minor new posterior change - does not apply to the problem)

What I should do to make the current situation the head?

git reflog:

```
dc82def (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): Fix conversion on all converters
adc7f05 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to HEAD@{3}
ffe3448 (remote-github/main, origin/master, master) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD~2
adc7f05 HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
7b5dbfb HEAD@{4}: commit: Remove tar
adc7f05 HEAD@{5}: commit: Fix conversion on all converters
588e4d5 HEAD@{6}: commit: Add multiline
ffe3448 (remote-github/main, origin/master, master) HEAD@{7}: commit: Add bulk page
84017af HEAD@{8}: commit: Add export possibility to all models
```

note: (I push to two repositories, hence what appears on ffe3448)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you asked to go to a revision in the reflog:

```
checkout: moving from master to HEAD@{3}
```

Which means that you ran something like:

```
git checkout HEAD@{3}
```

That will automagically get you into `detached HEAD` because you are no longer working with a branch. Now, why did you do that? I don't know..... but here's what you can do to get back on track:

```
git checkout 7b5dbfb
git reset --soft adc7f05
git commit --amend --no-edit
# now you have what you would like to have in master, right?
git branch -f master
git checkout master
# now you have to force-push in the other 2 repos (because you rewrote history)
```

If *you can't* force-push into the repos, you need to trick them with a revision following master:

```
git checkout 7b5dbfb
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "Correcting all the mess I did"
# this is a revision _after_ master that gets the content of the tree to what it was in 7b5dbfb
# if you like it:
git branch -f master
git checkout master
git push remote-github master:main
git push origin master
```